# Why JVM keeps loading the same (GUI) classes again and again with every instantiation?

Tags: java, swing, jvm, classloader, uimanager

I installed custom `ClassLoader` to track loaded classes at runtime, to catch some bad responsive moments, and I saw that some GUI classes are loaded every time when JFrame/JDialog is created:

```
loading: com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsPopupMenuSeparatorUI
loading: com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsTextFieldUI
loading: com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsTextAreaUI
loading: com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsComboBoxUI
loading: com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsPasswordFieldUI
```

**Why that classes are loaded by ClassLoader with every single dialog instantiation, not only once?**

another examples:

```
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dv.dtd.DTDDVFactoryImpl
```

my simple  `ClassLoader`:

```
public class MyClassLoader extends ClassLoader {

    public MyClassLoader ( ClassLoader parent ) {
        super( parent );
    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> loadClass( String name ) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        System.out.println( "loading: " + name );
        return super.loadClass( name );
    }
}
```

JVM parameter: `-Djava.system.class.loader=mupackage.MyClassLoader`

Comment: can you also show us your `ClassLoader` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loading the UI class it part of Swing's look&feel initialization process, see [UIDefaults.getUI(...)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/UIDefaults.html#getUI%28javax.swing.JComponent%29) for more info

Unless it is called millions of times, loadClass(...) is not very likely to be your problem here: if the class has already been loaded it will return very fast. Try using a profiler to pinpoint the cause of the slowdowns

Comment: But I'm initialising Look and Feel only once, at application main(). Given sample classes are loaded every time when dialog is created. Second, this is not only GUI-related, I gave examples of classes which are repeatably loaded when I do XML operations.

Comment: Calling loadClass(...) doesn't mean that the class is actually loaded, the first thing the class loader is to check if the class as already been loaded and, if so, returns it.

Comment: @Guillaume - your comment is the actual answer.